# phpmailer exchange server authentication

Tags: php, phpmailer, exchange-server

My mail send code:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    try {
        $mail->Host = 192.168.205.19;
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "mymailadress@mysite.com";
        $mail->Password = "mypassword";

        $mail->From = "mymailaddress@mysite.com";
        $mail->FromName = "My Mail Address";
        $mail->SetFrom("mymailaddress@mysite.cm", "My Mail Address");

        $mail->AddAddress('toaddress@mysite.com');

        $mail->Subject = "Test for subject";
        $mail->MsgHTML("Test my mail body");

        if ($mail->Send()) {
            $result = 1;
        } else {
            $result = "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $result = $e->errorMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $result;
```

Result?

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 evo.callpex.int Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 27 Nov 2012 17:45:24 +0200 
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

I'm using PHPMailer class for sent mail. And SMTP. I'm connecting to Exchange Mail server. But I have this error.

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that 1. Your username and password are correct, 2. that they work via something else like a mail client, 3. That your server is permitted to access the Exchange server for outbound delivery?

Comment: Based on the error, this may not be the problem but its worth checking.  Confirm that SMTP access is enabled on the Exchange server for the user you're trying to connect with.  Exchange may or may not be using certain types of encryption for authentication as well so special flags may be required to connect.  For example, when connecting to an Exchange server via IMAP, its not unusual to need `/novalidate-cert` and `/tls` in the connection.  I'm not sure how you'd go about doing that with PHPMailer though.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using Administrator credentials. Don't know why but even I was not able to send mail using PHPMailer with admin credentials(There may be some security measures applicable for Administrator details). Try giving any other user credentials, it will work.
It works for me with other user credentials.

And, In your code

```
  $mail->From = "mymailaddress@mysite.com";
  $mail->FromName = "My Mail Address";
  $mail->SetFrom("mymailaddress@mysite.cm", "My Mail Address");
```

$mail->SetFrom("mailid","name") itself will set From & FromName values. You no need to set that again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable `$mail->Host` should be a string like `$mail->Host = '192.168.205.19';` and not without quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know if this is sorted or not, but exchange servers typically don’t support SMTP. I believe it is possible to enable SMTP or create an SMTP connector though.