# PHPMailer connection refused with Exchange Server

Tags: php, smtp, exchange-server, phpmailer

I need to send mails from my system, but I can't connect to my SMTP server.
Mail server is Exchange.

PHP code (part of it):

```
        if ($options['is_smtp']) $this->_mailer->isSMTP();
        $this->_mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $this->_mailer->Host = $options['host'];
        $this->_mailer->Port = $options['port'];
        if(isset($options['smtp_secure']))
            $this->_mailer->SMTPSecure = $options['smtp_secure'];
        $this->_mailer->SMTPAuth = $options['smtp_auth'];
        if ($options['is_html']) $this->_mailer->isHTML();
        $this->_ready = true;
        $this->_mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Options in ini file:

```
mail.is_smtp = true
mail.host = "mail.example.com"
mail.port = 25
mail.smtp_auth = false
mail.smtp_secure = ""
mail.is_html = true
mail.from = "serwis@example.com"
mail.from_name = "Serwis Example"
```

Every time i try to send an email i get an error:

> 2015-12-21 13:13:21 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:
>   Connection refused (111) SMTP connect() failed

Server is configured to accept anonymous connections, from any ip. I tried using telnet and have something like this:

```
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Ukyu mail server
EHLO localhost
250-mail.example.com 
250-PIPELINING 
250-SIZE 64600000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN 
250-STARTTLS 
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250
8BITMIME
```

I've dug through many forums, answers and nothing helped.

Of course hostname is changed, due to security reasons.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587983/phpmailer-exchange-server-authentication

Comment: Try adding some debug to PHPMailer (or check its logs if it produces them) to see what port/host it is connecting to. My guess is that your `php.ini` settings should not make a difference, since you are handling this information in your PHP code.

Comment: You've set `SMTPDebug = 2`, yet you've not shown the debug output that generates. If it's a connection-level problem, try setting that to 4 for more verbose output.